# Package installation failed - psycopg2 in OsX

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried install the postgresSQL adapter for the Python:

```
$ pipenv install psycopg2
```

And I got this error:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (45527d)…
An error occurred while installing psycopg2==2.8.2...
```

The error stack is soo long, here the last lines:

```
(...)bin/../include/site/python3.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wq/wp6z48kj7_z3ynpkchsmqjp80000gn/T/pip-install-8ffakjrp/psycopg2/']
```

Any tip about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved installing just the binaries an others libs. Here is:

```
$ brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1 pkg-config
$ pipenv install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

1. `pipenv clean`
2. `pipenv install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: I've run into this in Jupyter and in Django where `psycopg2-binary` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of stuff but I think this worked better.

```sh
$ xcode-select --install
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```